# Lock Windows workstation programmatically in C#

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, pure-managed

I ran into this example for locking Windows workstation:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
...
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();

...
if (!LockWorkStation())
    throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()); // or any other thing
```

Is there a pure managed alternative to this snippet? Namely, without P-Invoke.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No there is not.  This is the best way to achieve this action.

Even if it was provided in the BCL, its implementation would almost certainly be identical to your sample.  It's not something the CLR would natively implement.

Comment: @RonKlein : Hey I want to does same thing. i.e programmatically Locking Windows Desktop and shows the Login screen without closing the session of the current user. 
This does same or something different???
thankx for your above solution it help me in many ways. Just make me clear above question.

Comment: @Hemang Rami, I think what you try to do is exactly what I was asking about: locking the workstation while keeping the current session active.

Comment: @RonKlein: I had done it using LOCKWORKSTATION Method. is it ok now. ?
I am not using rundll32.exe for locking Workstation.

Comment: @Hemang Rami, no problem. Just know that it works only on Windows OS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745788/c-sharp-lockout-account#13745833 provides the solution!