# How do I lock a windows workstation programmatically?

Tags: c#, user32

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lock Windows workstation programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263047/lock-windows-workstation-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

I am currently working on a visual studio windows form application that requires a function that locks the workstation. How can i make use of user32.dll to do a lock (Windows + L) when the function is called?

Comment: The dupe I posted is asking for a managed solution, but the non-managed solution is posted in the question itself :)

Comment: Not duplicate, the possible duplicate is not providing the solution!

Comment: The answer is in the question

Comment: The title of this question and the terminology used is misleading. You are locking the workstation, *not* performing an account lock-out (which is something else entirely).

Comment: Should think the tags are enough to assume "Windows", but anyway. =)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself, but I found [this](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/20698-C-Code-for-Lock-Computer.aspx) on google

`Process.Start(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe", "user32.dll,LockWorkStation");`

edit: I tried it, and it works!

edit2: Here's a [solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using `user32.dll` that doesn't start an external process.

`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;`

declare a method like this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

and then call `LockWorkStation();`.

Voilà

Comment: Yes, and the duplicate question is not providing your genius solution!

Comment: +1. Makes use of user32.dll, check, locks the workstation, check. Yeah, seems helpful. However, starting a subprocess for this might have unforeseen circumstances. Who knows. =)

Comment: Psst. **If** you copied that from the "duplicate" question, please attribute the original author. =)

Comment: Oh, didnt read it, sorry :P

Comment: Then you didn't copy, no attribution needed. =)

Comment: You will be a monster for this answer!!

Comment: Does this work when calling from a Windows Service?

Comment: [You don't want to use Rundll32](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130104-00/?p=5643), and C# has no issue with invoking methods from a DLL directly.

Comment: The latter method does not work from windowns service.