# Create a EXE File or BUTTON C#

Tags: c#, exe

*Hello, 
is there a way to create a **.exe** or **button** in C# to do the same as WIN+L?
Thanks*

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263047/lock-windows-workstation-programmatically-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745788/how-do-i-lock-a-windows-workstation-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
//using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();
```

And then just call within your `button_Click`:

```
LockWorkStation();
```