# Problem Using user32.dll in C# (Error 1008 An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.)

Tags: c#, uwp, token, user32, windows-8.1-universal

Hello legendary coders.

Flowing by my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697292/how-to-change-the-lockscreen-back-ground-find-windows-system-userprofile-dll) I tried to use `user32.dll` in windows universal application **(UWP)** in **C#** language but I encountered an error while trying to use the method I imported from that *.dll*

here is my code:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
private async void btnLock_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string path;
    if (Images.TryGetValue(selectedRadioButton.Name, out path))
    {
        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
        await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(file);
        if (!LockWorkStation())
            throw new Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
    }
}
```

as you can see I imported `LockWorkStation()` mthod from `user32.dll` and I used it in the event listener of a button. the `Images` is a `Dictionary<string,string>` and every thing is **Fine** unless the call to method `LockWorkStation()` it always return `false` and so the thrown error is 1008 I mentioned it in the *Title* The question is **Why?** and **how can I assign a token?**

> **Note:** any way,**any way** to lock the screen is admirable.

Comment: No, a UWP app cannot use that function.  It runs in a sandbox that can detect such violations, probably the source of the "invalid token" error.

Comment: can I use a service to call that or a web server on the target machine. @HansPassant

Comment: Try setting last error true and then get the window error : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.LockWorkStation

Comment: I tried it returns 5 I think it means (Access is denied) @jdweng

Comment: Yes it is access denied.  Do a search for "window lock screen access denied"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching a lot and being hopeless from directly lock the screen from the universal windows application platform I send a web request to a local web server and I made that web server to use the `user32.dll` and lock the screen.

here is the code in the UWP app:

```cs
       try
               {
                   HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
                   Uri uri = new Uri("http://localhost:8080/lock/");

                   HttpStringContent content = new HttpStringContent(
                       "{ \"pass\": \"theMorteza@1378App\" }",
                       UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
                       "application/json");

                   HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(
                       uri,
                       content);

                   httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   throw ex;
               }
```

and there is the code in the web server:

```cs
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern bool LockWorkStation();
        private static string LockTheScreen(HttpListenerRequest request)
        {
            var inputStream = request.InputStream;
            try
            {

                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(inputStream))
                {
                    JToken pass = JToken.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd());
                    if (pass.Value<string>("pass") == "theMorteza@1378App")
                    {
                        LockWorkStation();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                return "fail";
            }
            return "fail";
        }
```

**Note:** you can find how to make a simple web server [here](https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server)
**But:** you must install the web server and grant it's access for users.