# Set random lockscreen image from console app

Tags: c#, lockscreen, windows-11

I want to program a cute simple console app to set a random image from my image-folder as lock screen image. I just want to double click the program and, it searches the image folder, selects a random one and sets it as lock screen image without any user intervention.

My guess would be the following program:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Set Random Lock Screen Image");

var myPicturesFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
var imageFileList = Directory.GetFiles(myPicturesFolder);
if (imageFileList.Length > 0)
{
  var rnd = new Random();
  var iNr = rnd.Next(imageFileList.Length);
  var newImage = imageFileList[iNr];

  Console.WriteLine($"set {newImage}");
  var storageFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(newImage).GetResults();
  LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(storageFile).GetResults();
}
```

My only problem is, I can't find the assemblies containing `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` and `LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync` - what do I need to include to use these?

Or how else could I set the lock screen image? It does not need to be a console app, UWP would be fine, too, but I want to set the image without user interaction.

Comment: Where did you find the aforementioned functions? If you are copying them from a source you should be able to find the correct ```using``` directives to add.

Comment: From the MS sample https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/personalization/
But I could not deduct the assemblies from that project. Different platform use.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697292/how-to-change-the-lockscreen-back-ground-find-windows-system-userprofile-dll). Try using NuGet to install Uno.UI for StorageFile....

Comment: Are you using _UWP_ as described in [Lock screen personalization sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/personalization/): _Note: This sample is part of a large collection of UWP feature samples_ If not using _UWP_, search for [lock screen image  windows 10 registry](https://www.google.com/search?q=lock+screen+image++windows+10+registry)

Comment: Pity those samples do not work as console or other standalone app without user interaction :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Call Windows Runtime APIs in desktop apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance), specifically [Use the Target Framework Moniker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-enhance#net-6-and-later-use-the-target-framework-moniker-option):

- Change the target framework to gain access to Windows APIs:

```cs
<TargetFramework>net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
```

- Now you have access to those namespaces and APIs:

```cs
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System.UserProfile;

try
{
    var myPicturesFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
    var imageFileList = Directory.GetFiles(myPicturesFolder);
    var newImage = imageFileList[0];

    var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(newImage);
    await LockScreen.SetImageFileAsync(storageFile);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + ex);
}
```

I can execute the code though I receive the Access denied error understandably.  You will need to get the valid permission either through [Picker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers) or manifest permission.

Comment: Works like I wanted, thanks a lot!