# How do I lock a workstation from asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, webforms

I am trying to lock a windows workstation from an Asp.net website.

This is the code I was using: [Lock Windows workstation programmatically in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263047/lock-windows-workstation-programmatically-in-c-sharp)

It works when debugging on my local machine, but not when running on the server. Any idea why it isn't working?

I'm creating a program for school use as a kiosk application, and I want it to lock the computer when the website exits fullscreen or goes to another webpage to prevent students from accessing anything but the webpage. I know this isn't "foolproof" and there are ways around it - but I've successfully used it in normal C# desktop winforms in this setting.

Thank you!

Comment: That is probably a permission issue. You should tell us why it isn't working by checking the event log or your own log files.

Comment: @OguzOzgul Thank you. I'm new to this, so I'll figure out how to get into the log files on my web host.