# Is there a way to switch users from VB?

Tags: .net, vb.net

(Solved in another question, tl;dr: call LockWorkstation in user32.dll.)
I am writing an advanced shutdown menu for Windows, and I need to add the Switch Users function from the normal Shut Down Windows box.  Is there an EXE or other method which can bring the user to the login screen?
This answer on Super User [here](https://superuser.com/a/130508) suggests against using RunDll in favor of tsdiscon, however that does not exist anymore (in Windows 10 Home edition at least).

Comment: Hi Evan, the question as you put it is not easy to answer. You have not showed how you are approaching this problem. For example, the most "advanced" shutdown menu can be just a console message asking user to got to start menu and switch. So - what is your programming language? What have you tried so far? Where have you stuck? Add up meat to your question to make it good!

Comment: Check the linked question or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1263047/8967612). They're for C# but the concept is the same in VB, you basically call the `LockWorkStation` function in `user32.dll`.

Comment: ^ This solves my problem. Sorry for the crappy post